# Google Calendar Push Notifications: New events and event validation before/after creation

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-apis-explorer

I would like to now if the following functionality is supported by google calendar api:

1. Does the functionality provided by "Push notifications" include new events or just existing ones. Here is a copy paste from the documentation that let me doubt that new event notifications are supported "The Google Calendar API provides push notifications that let you watch for changes to resources.". So does this only apply to already existing resources (events on my case).
2. Is there a way to limit the availability on the google calendar. By this I mean setting a general limit (i.e working hours for a company for example from 9am to 5pm). And putting the logic further, is there a way to add more constraints. For example after I receive a notification of a new event created (if this functionality is provided), I check the event's data in my web-hook and let google calendar know that this event shouldn't be considered as valid.
   If these requirements are not provided already by google calendar API, I am open to any suggestions to accomplish this even if it takes more coding.

Just to make it clear. The context of these questions is when the user creates an event in their google calendar through google calendar web interface not through my application.

Comment: 1. Yes, 2. No. If you want constraints you have to write them yourself in your own application.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo, thank you